# python-home option fails when attempting to configure Django/mod_wsgi application in daemon mode on CentOS

Tags: python, django, centos, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application running on Centos 7.5 with Apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi 4.6.4. I'm having a hard time getting mod_wsgi to use the virtual environment I want it to use. I installed Python 3.6 via yum and used it to create a virtual environment. I compiled mod_wsgi from source, using the with-python option to point it to the correct Python binary. The (approximate) Apache configuration I expected to work, but which does not work, is the following:

```
# Required because of some third-party packages that use the 
# simplified GIL state API
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/path/to/venv python-path=/path/to/my/app
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/app/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/app/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration can't find any of the packages installed in the virtual environment. Dumping sys.path shows that the path doesn't contain /path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages as expected, but rather /lib/python3.6/site-packages (i.e. the system directory). The only way I've been able to get my app to run is by changing the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/path/to/my/app:/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

The first configuration (using `python-home` as recommended) does work for me on macOS 10.12 with Python 3.6 and mod_wsgi 4.5.24. A big difference between the two environments is the fact that SELinux is enabled on the CentOS server, but `audit2allow` shows nothing that explains my issue.

Comment: Set ``LogLevel`` to ``info`` or even ``debug``. Set ``WSGIVerboseDebugging On``. And go through http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html and validate your setup using the various checks. What additional information does that tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. I'm still not sure why I wasn't able to figure this out the first time, but it was an SELinux issue, as suspected. The problem was that everything under the virtual environment directory needed to have the `httpd_sys_content_t` context, except dynamically-loaded binary libraries, which need `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`. Once I did that, the `python-home` argument to `WSGIDaemonProcess` worked as expected.

Comment: Is is better to not place stuff under a home directory, it complicates lots of things.

Comment: it's been a while since this was active, but I'm hitting the same problem on Ubuntu, and unfortunately, I'm not familiar with setting up servers. how can I set the virtual env to `httpd_sys_content_t `?

Comment: You'd execute "chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /path/to/your/virtualenv". Use "-Rv" instead of "-R" if you want to see what changes it makes. If you have any dynamically-loaded binary libraries in there (usually files with the .so extension, e.g. for database adapters), you'd need to change their contexts with "chcon unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 /path/to/your/library.so".

If you're not experienced with SELinux, and this isn't a production server, might be better to just turn it off (sudo setenforce 0).